# Is it bad to store PHPSESSID into database?

Tags: php, database, session

For logging purposes I have to store the client PHPSESSID onto database.

Assuming that the session are expired, are there any bad practises linked to this? Can someone predict a PHPSESSID by reading the list?

Grateful to hear any situation where this can lead to a security problem.

Comment: _“For loggin purposes I have to store the client PHPSESSID onto database.”_ - why do you “have to”? _Explain_ stuff like this properly, instead of pretending it was an absolute unchangeable given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct and safe/secure way to keep a user logged in? cookies? session? PHP && MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566988/what-is-the-correct-and-safe-secure-way-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-cookies-sessi)

Answer (score 0):

People can set PHPSESSID's as they are stored locally meaning it is not safe to use in any form of security measure.

Please see this:
[What is the correct and safe/secure way to keep a user logged in? cookies? session? PHP && MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566988/what-is-the-correct-and-safe-secure-way-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-cookies-sessi)

Comment: The purpose is not to keep a user logged in. I just want to know if there is any possibile problem coming from knowing the past session_id of the users.